# Trouble with Date fields & Combining data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a MySQL Database, created using the following code (sure there are other tables too, but they're not relevant as per this specific question) :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Jeweller`.`Product_sales`;
CREATE TABLE `Jeweller`.`Product_sales` (
  `sale_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11),
  `value` float,
  FOREIGN KEY (`sale_id`) REFERENCES `Jeweller`.`Sales`(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `Jeweller`.`Products`(`id`),
  CHECK (`quantity`>0),
  CHECK (`value`>0)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Jeweller`.`Products`;
CREATE TABLE `Jeweller`.`Products` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `seller_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`product_category_id`) REFERENCES `Jeweller`.`Product_categories`(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`seller_id`) REFERENCES `Jeweller`.`Sellers`(`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Jeweller`.`Sales`;
CREATE TABLE `Jeweller`.`Sales` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How would you go about finding :

- Total earnings (quantity*value) per month (in 2013 - or any specific year for that matter)

I started by trying to get the month out of a `DATE` field (using DATEPART) but I'm already into trouble...

So, any ideas?

---

**P.S.**

- I'm not a guru with SQL
- The above is just an example, and not the exact code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT   MONTH(s.date) month, SUM(p.quantity * p.value)
FROM     Jeweller.Sales s
    JOIN Jeweller.Product_sales p ON p.sale_id = s.id
WHERE    s.date >= '2013-01-01' AND s.date < '2014-01-01'
GROUP BY month
```

Note that if the date range spans multiple years, you will need to group on both year *and* month.

Comment: Buddy, you are amazing. I'll still need a couple of minutes before I actually understand what you're doing. But it definitely works! Thanks a lot!